# Why is どうせやるなら more standard than どうせやったら?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I was working through the N3 完全マスター textbook and there is an example that says 「どうせ ____、面白い仕事がしたい。」The correct answer is やるなら, but another option was やったら.

At first, I thought maybe the reason why やったら is wrong is because たら requires the first clause to happen first. It doesn't make sense to want to do an interesting job after you've already started the job. But, you can say 「美味しいだったら、私も食べたい。」The first clause here is not a sequential event - it was always delicious or it never was.

Also, upon asking friends, they said どうせやったら is possible, but it sounds like a dialect. So what makes it sound "improper"?

Comment: 美味しいだったら is ungrammatical; you have to say 美味しいんだったら or 美味しかったら.

Answer (score 4):

(I originally started writing this as a comment)

なら feels to me like 'if you're going to do it', while たら feels like 'if you do this, then'. The difference is slight between なら and だったら for nouns, of course, but with verbs like this:

「どうせやるなら」 is 'if you're going to do it anyway' while 「どうせやったら」 just sounds wrong to my ear, unless it's part of a longer sentence where どうせ isn't directly modifying やる.

やるならやれ - 'if you're going to do it, do it'. やったらやれ - makes no sense. 'Once you do it, do it' (you've already done it).

And as I said the difference is much smaller with nouns and adjectives compared to verbs.　I'm guessing because they need なる to reflect a *change*.

Answer (score 2):

Hasegawa's *Japanese: A Linguistic Introduction* (2015) distinguishes following kinds of conditionals: content conditionals, epistemic conditionals, generic conditionals, speech-act conditionals.

The conditional おいしかったら、わたしもたべたい is arguably an epistemic one (the speaker's will to eat the food is dependent on her knowledge whether it tastes good).  According to Hasegawa, in an epistemic conditional たら does not require that the proposition in the dependent clause happen before the main clause.  These conditionals include

```
もし電気がついていたら、彼は家にいる。  (If the lights are on, then he's home.)
```

It's hard to classify the conditional どうせやるなら、おもしろい仕事がしたい according to Hasegawa's framework.  The other similar conditional やるならやれ, which appears in an another answer, does fit neatly into her analysis.  According to Hasegawa, if the proposition P in the dependent clause is "verifiable by the addressee", and the content of the main clause precedes P in time, then なら is the only grammatical connective.  Here verifiable propositions are contrasted with mere hypotheses (like future contingents, if I understand correctly).  Examples include

```
もし警官になるなら、柔道をならえ。 (If you want to be a police officer (in the future), then learn judo (now).)
```

I think that this analysis suggests, if not explains, why なら is preferred to たら in your example.  Since the proposition in the conditional is about the speaker's own action (やる), たら here sounds weirdly too hypothetical.  The verifiability criterion for choosing なら is clearly satisfied.

Finally, the dialectal どうせやったら is something completely different.  やったら here is the copula, not the verb やる。 The counterpart in the standard variant would be どうせだったら.

Answer (score 1):

Its most probably because なら is hypothetical, since it also evolved from the "nai stem"- 未然形 form, that was in classical japanese used as making hypothetical conditionals (among other uses). so どうせやるなら is rather more hypothetical than anything, どうせやったら is less, therefore どうせやるなら is more natural. otherwise i would probably learn this as a "set phrase".

Answer (score 1):

どうせやったら is correct in Kansai region (as you mention, this is spoken dialect in Kansai), but in the standard Japanese, どうせやるなら or どうせなら　sounds correct.
In the standard Japanese, 「どうせやったら、面白い仕事がしたい」 sounds improper because やったら is past tense. Although you haven't started an interesting job, you speak like you already finished the job.